# I need to declare a Random instance globally. Is there a better way?

Tags: java, random

I have 2 classes: `Being` and `Environment`. Both classes may at some point need to generate a random number.

Originally, before Being needed random numbers, I had an instance of `Random` as a member of `Environment` which I would just call `nextInt()` on. Now `Being` needs random numbers, and I'm not sure the best set-up.

My first thought was to give each instance of `Being` and `Enviro` it's own instance of `Random`, but it seemed wasteful.

Then I thought of storing a Random in `Environment`, and somehow passing it in to each `Being`, but I figured that I would probably end up needing to store it in each instance anyway; so it wouldn't be any better then the first idea.

Then I thought of making a separate class with a `public static` instance of Random; but that means I have 2 classes just to get a random number (the Random class I'm using is actually a derived class of Random)

Finally, I thought of declaring it globally. That leaves 2 questions though:

- How do I do this? From what I've seen from Java so-far (I'm fairly new), it isn't possible to have a instance of a object declared globally.
- Is this the best solution? What else should I do?

I don't not care about reproducibility, and it's not SecureRandom.

Comment: I don't think Random is such an expensive object to create. There's nothing wrong with having two instances in different classes.

Comment: What's wrong with a private static field for each type? There's no point in giving each instance its own `Random` object so you'd end up with only 2 objects.

Comment: I didn't think of just making it static to the class. Whoops.

Comment: It actually will make a difference if you are using Random vs SecureRandom... if you are using Random then using a single vs multiple `Random` objects will have effect on the numbers generated...On the other hand, using single or multiple objects of `SecureRandom` has no effect

Comment: In terms of being wasteful...do not worry much about it

Comment: @Multithreader: Is this part of the SecureRandom spec that all instances are basically backed by the same source? How does this work with multiple threads?

Comment: @Thilo my argument goes for the randomness of the generated numbers. `Random` produces predictable numbers. However, `SecureRandom` does not. Also, both `Random` and `SecureRandom` are not thread safe. So to pass one object in multithreading environment, you need something like the singleton design as posted below. Otherwise, you will run into thread safety problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not at all wasteful to have multiple instances of `Random`. The only reason I would not do so is if the random numbers need to be reproducible for some purpose. You did not mention wanting to control the random seed or sequence, so it seems you can just have multiple `Random` instances.

Comment: Even if I had 100+ instances of Being, it wouldn't have a noticeable overhead?

Comment: `SecureRandom` is kind of heavy, a normal `Random` won't be noticeable. But you were talking of two instances, one for each class. If `Being` and `Environment` each have a static Random, that makes two instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It is a singleton (meaning it can have a max of one object at anytime). You can get an instance using the static method as: `MyRandom random = MyRandom.getInstance();`

```
    import java.security.SecureRandom;


public class MyRandom {
    final private static MyRandom singleton = new MyRandom();
    final private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    //it is important to keep this, so no one can make multiple instances of this class
    private MyRandom() {
    }

    final synchronized static public MyRandom getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }
    final synchronized public int nextInt() {
        return random.nextInt();
    }
    final synchronized public long nextLong() {
        return random.nextLong();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing this would be to have an interface:

```
public interface MyRandom {
    static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
}
```

then have your `Being` and `Environment` classes implement the `MyRandom` interface